# Eclipse code completion exclusively based on javadocs

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javadoc

Is it possible?

I'm developing for a application server that in runtime give me access to some specific classes. I also have the `javadocs` related to those `jars`.

Importing all the deployed jar into Eclipse would be much harder than getting auto-completion working exclusively from `javadocs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You'll need the binary jars in the eclipse build path to be able to compile your source code.

Comment: The building process is completely out of this process, because is accomplished with some external plugins. I would like to be able to do this for coding purpose only.

Comment: Try it, but I'm pretty sure it's not possible. I don't even know how you could tell Eclipse to use the javadoc. It's notmaly done by associating a javadoc jar or URL with a binary jar in the build path.

Comment: I can import a javadoc zip file as an external dependency. After that, Eclipse will recognize the packages, but not the classes (probably because of the folder structure).
If there's no better answer (by better I mean a answer that fixes my problem), I'll give you the answer. Thanks.